# Java - Audible Lag with Custom MIDI Sequencer using PPQ Ticks for Timing

Tags: java, performance, audio, time, midi

I have been trying to implement my own **asynchronous MIDI sequencer in Java** that sends ShortMessage's to VST's by processing lists of MidiEvent's. I need performance to be optimal so that there will be no audible delay when listening to the audio output.

The problem is that there definitely is audible lag as the ticks increment inaccurately (increments either too fast or too slow at times which messes up all MidiEvent's timing).

Here is the code of the sequencer below:

```
package com.dranithix.spectrum.vst;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;

import com.synthbot.audioplugin.vst.vst2.JVstHost2;

/**
 * 
 * @author Kenta Iwasaki
 * 
 */
public class VstSequencer implements Runnable {
    public static long BPM = 128L, PPQ = 4L;
    private long oneTick = (60000L / (BPM * PPQ)) * 1000000;

    private Map<MidiEvent, Long> currentEvents = new ConcurrentHashMap<MidiEvent, Long>();
    private long startTime = System.nanoTime(), elapsedTicks = 0;
    private JVstHost2 vst;

    public VstSequencer(JVstHost2 vst) {
        this.vst = vst;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (System.nanoTime() - startTime >= oneTick) {
                elapsedTicks++;
                startTime = System.nanoTime();
            }

            Iterator<MidiEvent> it = currentEvents.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                MidiEvent currentEvent = it.next();
                long eventTime = currentEvent.getTick() - elapsedTicks;
                if (eventTime <= 0) {
                    vst.queueMidiMessage((ShortMessage) currentEvent
                            .getMessage());
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void queueEvents(List<MidiEvent> events) {
        Map<MidiEvent, Long> add = new HashMap<MidiEvent, Long>();
        for (MidiEvent event : events) {
            event.setTick(event.getTick() + elapsedTicks);
            add.put(event, event.getTick());
        }
        currentEvents.putAll(add);
    }

    public void queueEvent(MidiEvent event) {
        event.setTick(event.getTick() + elapsedTicks);
        currentEvents.put(event, event.getTick());
    }
}
```

How can we improve the performance of this system? Can we ensure that there will be no audible delay for this sort of system (for example: a fixed timestep)?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Just to isolate causes of audible lag, I can confirm that there is no lag from the VST itself or from the framework sending the MIDI Messages to the VST. It has to do with the tick-based timing system presently used in the sequencer.

**SOLVED:** I fixed the issue by having the VST events become processed parallel to the event sequencer itself by including the VST event processing code in the same thread (they were originally on separate threads). To whomever out there reads this and has been scavenging around for sequencing MIDI events to JVstHost2 or any similar Java VST Host library, feel free to use parts of fixed code for your own projects as it has been very difficult for me to find proper VST sequencing online due to VST being a commercial format that is rarely ever touched with Java.

**Solved Code:**

```
package com.dranithix.spectrum.vst;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiEvent;
import javax.sound.midi.ShortMessage;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioFormat;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.SourceDataLine;

import com.synthbot.audioplugin.vst.vst2.JVstHost2;

/**
 * 
 * @author Kenta Iwasaki
 * 
 */
public class VstSequencer implements Runnable {
    private static final float ShortMaxValueAsFloat = (float) Short.MAX_VALUE;
    public static float BPM = 120f, PPQ = 2f;
    private static float oneTick = 60000f / (BPM * PPQ);

    private List<MidiEvent> currentEvents = new ArrayList<MidiEvent>();
    private long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(), elapsedTicks = 0;
    private JVstHost2 vst;

    private final float[][] fInputs;
    private final float[][] fOutputs;
    private final byte[] bOutput;
    private int blockSize;
    private int numOutputs;
    private int numAudioOutputs;
    private AudioFormat audioFormat;
    private SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

    public VstSequencer(JVstHost2 vst) {
        this.vst = vst;

        numOutputs = vst.numOutputs();
        numAudioOutputs = Math.min(2, numOutputs);

        blockSize = vst.getBlockSize();
        fInputs = new float[vst.numInputs()][blockSize];
        fOutputs = new float[numOutputs][blockSize];
        bOutput = new byte[numAudioOutputs * blockSize * 2];

        audioFormat = new AudioFormat((int) vst.getSampleRate(), 16,
                numAudioOutputs, true, false);
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class,
                audioFormat);

        sourceDataLine = null;
        try {
            sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat, bOutput.length);
            sourceDataLine.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException lue) {
            lue.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        try {
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();
        } finally {
            super.finalize();
        }
    }

    private byte[] floatsToBytes(float[][] fData, byte[] bData) {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < blockSize; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numAudioOutputs; j++) {
                short sval = (short) (fData[j][i] * ShortMaxValueAsFloat);
                bData[index++] = (byte) (sval & 0x00FF);
                bData[index++] = (byte) ((sval & 0xFF00) >> 8);
            }
        }
        return bData;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (Thread.interrupted()) {
                break;
            }
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= oneTick) {
                elapsedTicks++;
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            vst.processReplacing(fInputs, fOutputs, blockSize);
            sourceDataLine.write(floatsToBytes(fOutputs, bOutput), 0,
                    bOutput.length);

            Iterator<MidiEvent> it = currentEvents.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                MidiEvent currentEvent = it.next();
                long eventTime = currentEvent.getTick() - elapsedTicks;
                if (eventTime <= 0) {
                    vst.queueMidiMessage((ShortMessage) currentEvent
                            .getMessage());
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void queueEvents(List<MidiEvent> events) {
        for (MidiEvent event : events) {
            event.setTick(event.getTick() + elapsedTicks);
        }
        currentEvents.addAll(events);
    }

    public void queueEvent(MidiEvent event) {
        event.setTick(event.getTick() + elapsedTicks);
        currentEvents.add(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Following is a good paper on real-time, low latency audio processing in Java. There are many issues. Sorry I don't have an actual answer, though. I'd like to learn more about VST programming and am going to lurk. Thought you might find the article interesting, though. http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/p/pod/dod-idx?c=icmc;idno=bbp2372.2007.131

Comment: Thanks a lot for the article! I am actually doing this project for two science project competitions, and the read definitely lets me keep in mind of potential audio latency issues with Java.

Also, I have managed to fix the issue by having the VST process events parallel to the event sequencer :). I edited the thread to include the new code.

Comment: Thank you for making your code available! I have bookmarked them for future reference. I have a Java FM synth that I made and some effects that I was hoping to someday turn into VSTs that would function in my DAW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the problem is:

```
event.setTick(event.getTick() + elapsedTicks);
add.put(event, event.getTick());
```

The stream of events presumably already have time-stamps, so there is no need add `elapsedTicks` to them. This simply means they get later and later as time progresses.

There are several very obvious ways to improve the performance of the code above. Whether they are the cause of your problems is hard to say:

1: Don't busy-wait: The code above has no means of blocking until there's something to do (a `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't provide blocking behaviour). Instead it loops continuously burning CPU cycles, even when there's nothing to do.  This kind of behaviour is often penalised by operating system schedulers.  Your thread can't schedule events when it's not running, and its current design encourages this.

2: The use of of a HashMap keyed with MIDIEvent for `currentEvents` is a poor choice and inefficient.  You need to iterate the entire container to find events that need delivering to the VST. Furthermore, since there is no ordering guarantee, you potentially deliver events falling in the current tick out of order.  Consider using a `SortedMap` where the key is the delivery time.  Events are now ordered, with the soonest at the beginning of the structure.  Delivering events is cheap.

A further potential problem lies with this line - it won't cause irregular timing, but I may mean that oneTick is wrong:

```
private long oneTick = (60000L / (BPM * PPQ)) * 1000000;
```

The division by `BPM * PPQ` causes a truncation.  Perform the multiplication first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the performance tips! I've actually managed to solve the audible latency by processing VST events parallel to the sequencer itself, however I have gotten a better idea of improving efficiency of code through your tips :).

I've also replaced the Map with a mere ArrayList seeing that the ticks for each event may as well be updated within the thread's loop rather than having it as a key.